# Getting NA instead of datetime when converting string to datetime

Tags: r, datetime, na

5 people voted to close this post, but since it has an answer, the site warns against deleting it altogether.

To make this as useful as possible for future readers - if you make a syntax mistake in doing string to date-time conversions, the warnings and errors you get (if any) may not point you to the cause of the problem.  Instead, your output gets replaced with `NA`.

Here is the original sample code w/ warnings and errors. 
Sample Dates:  `5/20/2017 7:28` and `5/20/2017 2:28:57`

Sample code:

```
library(lubridate)
ymd_hms('5/20/2017 7:28', tz = "America/New_York")

> Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found. 

strptime("5/20/2017 7:29:00","%m/%d/%Y %H:%M/%S")

as.Date("5/20/2017 7:29:00")

> Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

as.POSIXct('5/20/2017 7:29:00',format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS")
```

There was a post that suggested the following for others encountering the `NA` error for other reasons:

`lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")`

In this case: a look at the documentation concerning the formatters of the date string could have avoided this question but at the time the post was made, I did not realize this.  The key to solving a problem is understanding what is wrong and looking in the right place for it.  A good example of working code that has the formatters set up right is in the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: This works without error: `strptime(c("5/20/2017 7:29:30", "5/22/2017 7:58"),"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `lubridate` solution is my personal favourite.  You are making two mistakes when using it, though:

1. Using `ymd`, meaning *year-month-day*.  Instead, use `mdy` for *month-day-year*.
2. Using `hms` for *hours-minutes-seconds*, but not supplying seconds.

Try

```
> mdy_hms('5/20/2017 7:28:00', tz = "America/New_York")
[1] "2017-05-20 07:28:00 EDT"
```

or

```
> mdy_hm('5/20/2017 7:28', tz = "America/New_York")
[1] "2017-05-20 07:28:00 EDT"
```